# Downloading file from a folder in S3 Bucket using golang

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I am trying to download a tar file inside a folder from a S3 bucket using the AWS Go SDK V2. I am able to list all the items in the bucket, but not able to download the file.
Here is the code I am using:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/credentials"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/s3/manager"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3"
)
const (
   AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = ""
   AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = ""
   BUCKET = "storage"
   REGION = ""
  

)
type S3ListObjectsAPI interface {
    ListObjectsV2(ctx context.Context,
        params *s3.ListObjectsV2Input,
        optFns ...func(*s3.Options)) (*s3.ListObjectsV2Output, error)
}

func GetObjects(c context.Context, api S3ListObjectsAPI, input *s3.ListObjectsV2Input) (*s3.ListObjectsV2Output, error) {
    return api.ListObjectsV2(c, input)
}

func main() {
    
    
    creds := credentials.NewStaticCredentialsProvider(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, "")

    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(), config.WithCredentialsProvider(creds),config.WithRegion(REGION))
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("error: %v", err)
        return
    }

    client := s3.NewFromConfig(cfg)

    input := &s3.ListObjectsV2Input{
        Bucket: aws.String(BUCKET),
    }

    resp, err := GetObjects(context.TODO(), client, input)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Got error retrieving list of objects:")
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Objects in " + BUCKET + ":")
    today := time.Now()
    
    downloader := manager.NewDownloader(client)

    for _, item := range resp.Contents {
        diff := today.Sub(*item.LastModified)
        if diff.Hours() <= 24 {
            fmt.Println("Name:          ", *item.Key)
            fmt.Println("Last modified: ", *item.LastModified)
            fmt.Println("Size:          ", item.Size)
            fmt.Println("Storage class: ", item.StorageClass)
            fmt.Println("")
            newFile, err := os.Create(*item.Key)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
            }
            defer newFile.Close()
            numBytes, err := downloader.Download(context.TODO(), newFile, &s3.GetObjectInput{
                Bucket: aws.String(BUCKET),
                Key:    aws.String(*item.Key),
            })
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("Error in downloading the backup %v", item.Key)
            }
            fmt.Printf("Downloaded %v bytes", numBytes)

        }

    }

    fmt.Println("Found", len(resp.Contents), "items in bucket", BUCKET)
    fmt.Println("")
}
```

It keeps showing me the error that "no such file or directory". is there something that I am missing?

Comment: That's probably coming from `os.Create`, no? Or do you have a directory on the host that matches the object key (without the last path element)?

Comment: that means I should provide a different name in OS.Create()?

Comment: You can provide whatever name you like as long as it is a valid file path on the host. For example, if the name contains multiple path separators then you need to ensure that a corresponding directory exists on the host, if it doesn't exist then you need to create it *before* you call `os.Create`.

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/tmKeAF3YyLk -- If your `*item.Key` does NOT contain any separators then the directory-does-not-exist is not the issue. And keep in mind that if want your program to run on Windows you'll need to account for the fact that, by convention, s3 object keys are split by `"/"` and not `"\"`.

Comment: Thanks @mkopriva this really helped me. I was specifying a wrong path.